# check dynamic key is not empty in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this

```
$groupData = [
    [
        "Text Field Two" => "Value 1 Row 1",
        "" => "Value 2 Row 1",      //empty/missing key name
        "" => "Value 3 Row 1",      //empty/missing key name
        "JL" => ""                  //empty/missing value
    ],
    [
        "Text Field Two" => "Value 1 Row 2",
        "Justice League" => "Value 2 Row 2",
        "" => "Value 3 Row 2",      //empty/missing key name
        "" => "Value 4 Row 2"       //empty/missing key name
     ]
];
```

I want to check the key of an array is empty/missing so I can show message otherwise I wanna manipulate the array. In above array some keys are empty/missing.

```
foreach($groupData as $key => $value) {
    if(empty($value['emptykey'])) {
        return message/error
    } else {
        further code process here
    }
}
```

But the problem is the keys are dynamic and can't get the key name static to check if they are empty/missing.

If anyhow I get all the key name dynamically in loop so I also want to check their value too.

Comment: I've read this question 3 times and I still don't understand it. How are keys being supplied by the user?

Comment: You should provide an exemple : input data and awaited output data

Comment: can you please specify how a user is sending dynamic key and what you exactly want to validate. You should provide a proper example

Comment: @mulquin I update my question so please check it out.

Comment: @HammadAhmedkhan check my updated question now.

Comment: please check my answer @user2727841

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear to me what you are expecting and where the keys come from, BUT:

When using the same key in 1 array, you will loose all the values, except the latter one. SO, looking at your array:

```
$groupData = [
    [
        "Text Field Two"=> "Value 1 Row 1",
        ""=> "Value 2 Row 2",
        ""=> "Value 3 Row 3",
        "JL"=> "Value 4 Row 3"
    ],
    [
        "Text Field Two"=> "Value 1 Row 2",
        "Justice League"=> "Value 2 Row 2",
        ""=> "Value 3 Row 2",
        ""=> "Value 4 Row 2"
     ]
];
```

Will effectively result in:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Text Field Two"]=>    string(13) "Value 1 Row 1"
    [""]=>                  string(13) "Value 3 Row 3"
    ["JL"]=>                string(13) "Value 4 Row 3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Text Field Two"]=>    string(13) "Value 1 Row 2"
    ["Justice League"]=>    string(13) "Value 2 Row 2"
    [""]=>                  string(13) "Value 4 Row 2"
  }
}
```

So with that in mind, could you rephrase your question?

Comment: I update my question now.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($groupData as $key => $value) {
    foreach($groupData as $nk=> $nv) {
     if(empty($nk)){
        return //error
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it could be done in nested loop but I need this in one loop.